# Tkinter - How to add additional check box?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a checklist with another additional checkbox.

Here is what I have:

```
var12 = IntVar()

self.Checkbox = Checkbutton(right_frame, text="Address & contact details correct", variable=var12)
self.Checkbox.grid(column = 1, row = 12, sticky = W)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Here's what I am trying to do:

[image]

How do I add another checkbox? And link it to the same `var12`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Checkbox = Checkbutton(right_frame, variable=var12)
Checkbox2 = Checkbutton(right_frame, text="Address & contact details correct", variable=var12)
Checkbox.grid(column = 1, row = 12, sticky = W)
Checkbox2.grid(column = 2, row = 12, sticky = W)
```

[image]

Comment: perfect! I will need to create new variables as it ticks both of them.. will add something like `var12v2`